# Hear sounds from Unimodem Half Duplex Audio Device over RDP

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

is it somehow possible to hear the sounds from an "Unimodem Half Duplex Audio Device" ( It's a 56k modem ) over an RDP session? I can hear every system sounds, but the sounds from the modem isn't hearable via the RDP session.

Has anyone an idea how it is possible?

Thank you Regards

Comment: Modem sounds are typically made by a small speaker physically on the modem itself, and are not sent through system audio channels. I can't say for sure whether this is your setup, but I personally have not seen a modem that did not have its own speaker. As these sounds only occur on the modem, there would be no way to send them via RDP unless you used a microphone and routed that audio.

Comment: Hello, no it is a small USB 56k modem without any built in speaker, it uses the PC speaker to play the sound. As I run this on a VMware I can use the remote console and there I can hear the sounds from the modem, but if I use RDP the sound is not transmitted :/.

Comment: You mention you can hear system sounds, but if you open an audio player or play a video over RDP, can you hear those sounds?

Comment: yes, I can. Every "normal" system sound or sound via media player etc. works fine. But the modem seems to be it's own sound device.
If I am on the PC via the VMware remote console I can see the modem device appear in the sound mixer, when it plays sound. If I look at it via RDP everything changes to "Remote audio" and the modem doesn't appear in the audio mixer.